# Contact Form 7- problem with submit button

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

the problem is I am making dual language website with JS and CSS only. Language change is triggered with button, here's a sample of JS for reference:

```
function languageSwitch() {
  var state = $('.lang-pl:visible').length ? 'pl' : 'en';
  if (state === 'pl') {
    $('.lang-pl').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lang-en').css('display', 'inherit');
  } else {
    $('.lang-en').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lang-pl').css('display', 'inherit');
  }
  return false;
}
```

Everything looked great, but I hit a brick wall when it came to translating submit button. On regular fields like labels and even [acceptance] it wasn't problem and it worked like a charm:

```
<label> <span class="lang-pl">Imię i nazwisko *</span> <span class="lang-en">Name and surname *</span> [text* your-name] </label>
```

But with this code submit button isn't working- it's showing 'lang-pl' version before and after switching languages:

`[submit <span class="lang-pl">Wyślij</span> <span class="lang-en">Send</span>]`

Anyone have idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried setting css `display`to `block` or `inline`instead of `inherit`? Also, is your `languageSwitch()` function called at all? It's defined in your code, but not actually called.

Comment: Just tried, didn't work- I am not sure about Contact Form 7 itself- maybe built-in elements like [submit] wasn't made for my purpose

Comment: Is your `languageSwitch()` function called somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, it's starting at document.ready(); and all parts of website works perfectly- that one button isn't.

Comment: I would say it's an issue with your conditional `$('.lang-pl:visible').length`, maybe you can try to grab the current language from another element and then run the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just found solution:

I've switched default `[submit]`
with

```
<button id='submit' class='wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit'><span class="lang-pl">Wyślij</span> <span class="lang-en">Send</span></button>
```

and it works like a charm, now just styling in CSS